# When using a pivot function can I return a sum of values that were spread?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

In short, the following returns the count of cyl in mtcars spread/pivoted wider across columns:

```
> mtcars %>%
+   group_by(cyl) %>% 
+   summarise(Count = n()) %>% 
+   pivot_wider(names_from = cyl,
+               values_from = Count)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
    `4`   `6`   `8`
  <int> <int> <int>
1    11     7    14
```

I would like to maintain the value of values_from, the Count field in my example, showing the total so that at a glance, on my real data I can see the total sum of Count that was spread for each row. In this case that would be 11 + 7 + 14 = 32.

Is there a way I can force pivot_wider to maintain the values in values_from as well as spreading them across columns?

EDIT:
Desired output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  Count   `4`   `6`   `8`
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1    32    11     7    14
```

Comment: Hi @RonakShah, I have added desired output to my post

Comment: Why not just `with(mtcars, c(Count=length(cyl), table(cyl)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a column after the `summarise` with `mutate` and then do the `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mtcars %>%
   group_by(cyl) %>%
   summarise(Count1 = n()) %>%
   mutate(Count = sum(Count1)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = cyl, values_from = Count1)
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#  Count   `4`   `6`   `8`
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1    32    11     7    14
```

Answer (score 2):

We can add the sum of values which were spread later using `rowSums`

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  count(cyl) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = cyl, 
                     values_from = n) %>%
  mutate(Count = rowSums(.))

# A tibble: 1 x 4
#    `4`   `6`   `8` Count
#  <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#1    11     7    14    32
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak for answering. I found Akrun's answer more helpful in this instance because there are other fields in my real data that I don't want included in rowSums and the other approach of duplicating the values_from field accounts for that. Thanks all the same

Comment: @DougFir you can select specific columns to sum upon based on position `mutate(Count = rowSums(.[1:3]))` or by name `mutate(Count = rowSums(.[c("4", "6", "8")]))`.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, that's handy to know :)